# Drupal - Flagging nodes on behalf of another user(programmatically)

Tags: php, drupal, flags

I have a custom module which allows a user to invite friends to see his/her favourite(flagged) nodes.

Upon the invitation/registration.. I want to be able to duplicate the (inviter)users flags for the new(invited) user.

i read http://drupal.org/node/305086 and it says to use:

```
function flag($action, $content_id, $account = NULL, $skip_permission_check = FALSE)
```

however regardless what value i put in for $account the new flag is not created for the new user.

can anybody assist please!

Comment: Can you add some example code of what you currently are doing.

Answer (score 5):

`$account` must be a user object, implemented with `$account = user_load(array('uid' => 123));`.  Are you doing this?